# Can I create a LiveUSB for installing Lubuntu without using a CD?

Tags: installation, lubuntu, live-usb

I'm trying to understand how to create a LiveUSB for installing Lubuntu. I'm currently downloading the .iso, and I'm trying to understand whether I can create a LiveUSB for installation without first using a CD.

I'd like to avoid using a CD if possible, but if a CD is necessary to create a LiveUSB, then I expect that I would just skip the USB entirely, and install from the CD.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'd like to avoid using a CD if possible, but if a CD is necessary to create a LiveUSB, then I expect that I would just skip the USB entirely

A physical CD is **not** necessary to create a LiveUSB; you just need the ISO image. Use [UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) to create the LiveUSB; just point it to the ISO and to the drive/device that is your USB stick.

*However*, depending on how old your computer is, it may not support booting from USB; in that case you can use a CD to "kick-start" the USB.

Comment: Thanks. Any guess whether a laptop from 2005 would support booting from USB?

Comment: Most probably. The easy way to check is to plugin any USB (can even be blank), reboot and press whatever F-key the screen says can be used to select a boot up device. If the USB is in the list you're good to go!

Answer (score 1):

Download and install UnetBootin: http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 1):

The official Ubuntu [page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) would be helpful .

Comment: That page might answer my question, but I didn't see it. It seems to presume the existence of a CD.

Comment: It says Ubuntu Cd or ISO file , since you are downloading the ISO image , CD is utterly unnecessary  if you want bootable USB-stick. If you are using Ubuntu to create Live Usb-stick use usb-creator  from software manager. Please take a look at the whole page or just interested contents from its Right Side Menu.
My insistence to read it whole is just to remove your doubts of any inconvenience regarding it.